# Get multiple values from a function in yii2

Tags: arrays, function, api, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a function in my `Model` which is passed a single value and in which I have a query which is giving me two results.

```
 public static function updImgtbl($id)
{
    $total_images = 0;
    $images_uploaded = 0;

    $sqlquery = "SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN ims.`installation_id` = $id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_images, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ims.`image_upload_flag` = 1 AND ims.`installation_id` = $id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS images_uploaded
    FROM    `installation_images_site` ims
    INNER JOIN `installations` ins ON ins.`id` = ims.`installation_id`
    WHERE   (ims.`image_upload_flag` = 1 AND ims.`installation_id` = $id)
    OR (ims.`installation_id` = $id) 
    GROUP BY ims.`installation_id`";

    $pt = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sqlquery)->queryAll();

    foreach ($pt as $val)
    {
        $total_images= $val['total_images'];
        $images_uploaded = $val['images_uploaded'];
    }
    return ["total_images" => $total_images, "images_uploaded"=>$images_uploaded];
}
```

This function is called from an `API`

```
 $response = Installations::updImgtbl($install_id);
        print_r($response);
        exit();
```

The response is below

```
Array
(
  [total_images] => 4
  [images_uploaded] => 1
)
```

But I want to get these values in a variable in my API. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply:

```
list($total_images, $images_uploaded) = array_values($response);
```

Then, you have `total_images` value in `$total_images` variable and `images_uploaded` in `$images_uploaded` variable.

I mean:

```
list($total_images, $images_uploaded) = Installations::updImgtbl($install_id);
echo $total_images; // 4
echo $images_uploaded; // 1
```

You can read more about `list` in [official doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php).

Another way is using [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function. For example:

```
$response = Installations::updImgtbl($install_id);
extract($response);   
echo $total_images; // 4
echo $images_uploaded; // 1
```

Comment: ` list('total_images'=>$total_images, 'images_uploaded'=>$images_uploaded) = Installations::updImgtbl($install_id);
            print_r($total_images);
            print_r($images_uploaded);
            exit();` it works for me :)